# What is the best Domain Registrar?

Tags: domain, internet, domain-registrar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who is a good registrar these days?](https://serverfault.com/questions/31392/who-is-a-good-registrar-these-days)

**What is your favorite (US) Domain Registrar?**

While this is not specifically a programming question, I host a good number of websites. I've used a handful of different registrars in the past, but to be honest, I've never really been happy with any of them.

I'm specifically looking for a registrar that does the following, but I'm not that picky if it gets the job done well:

- Costs around $10 per year. More Expensive up front is not a huge deal
- Offers Bulk Registrations. I don't want to have to complete their registration process 10 times to register 10 domains.
- Has a reliable, decent interface.
- Has People I can talk to on the phone in an emergency. While I've never needed to call my registrar before, It's sort of a company policy that we don't pay for services without real people offering support.

Edit: Make that a *US* Domain Registrar! :)

Comment: I assume you are looking for a US domain registrar? ;)

Comment: Yet, even though you realize it's not a programming related question, you still felt the need to clutter up the internet with it? :-)

Comment: While it's not programming specific, I think that most web programmers  also have to deal with domain registration at least periodically, so I felt that this question fit rather well here. Stackoverflow is the first place I thought to look for an answer, but noone had asked it yet.

Comment: phone support for $10/year. I would not count on it, even if they claim they offer this service on their website.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/31392/who-is-a-good-registrar-these-days

Answer (score 4):

I've used GoDaddy, but never will in the future. They happen to be a customer of ours, and knowing how their environment is setup scares me.

I've heard many good things about [pairnic.com](http://pairnic.com).

Answer (score 3):

Namecheap.com, I have been using this for the past 3 years and would never think to change. I have accounts on all other popular ones for when I buy domains off people (GoDaddy etc) and I think they are all crap. I would use NameCheap for everything if I could.

Comment: Using Namecheap for the first time on this recommendation. Will report back with results if anyone cares.

Comment: @pcampbell Any news since you used them?

Comment: @pcampbell was killed by a namecheap hitman, so we're forced to try it out ourselves.

Comment: Namecheap has worked out very well for us. Recommended!

Answer (score 0):

I use heartinternet.com, simply because they allow bulk registration and bulk management < a very useful feature if you ever need to change the nameservers of 150 domains! :D

Answer (score 0):

I use [netfirms](http://www.netfirms.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [register4less.com](http://register4less.com) and am pretty happy with them. Free whois privacy, so your name/address is not plastered all over whois records, plus simple and usable web interface.

Answer (score 0):

By far the best company I’ve found is  www.WebPricedRight.com

I have used over half a dozen companies over the last 9 years. I am a Graphic Designer and I service over 20 clients. Most of the service providers that I used promised the world but just raised their prices the next year. For the last 3 years I have been working with Web Priced Right. I wasn't sure at first because their prices were relatively low compared to other options out there. It was the best decision I've ever made!

I am currently hosting over 40 websites with them and never once have had a second of down time. They have never raised their prices on me and the tech support is unreal. They have some of the most experienced and knowledgeable technical staff that I have ever worked with. In fact this is the reason that I started this blog...

Never in all my years have I had a tech go out of his/her way to make sure that I was taken care of. It is truly a level of support that is unsurpassed in this industry. I whole-heartedly recommend Web Priced Right to you and look forward to hearing your feedback.

Comment: Are you an employee of WPR?